# why is the infinitive "be" used instead of "are" in the sentence "Here be samples."?

Tags: infinitives

In the image below, which is from an article webpage about a smartphone from Forbes, there is the sentence, "Here be samples." right above the pictures.

> Here be samples.

I wonder why the infinitive form "be" was used here instead of the present simple form "are".

[image: An article webpage about a smartphone camera]

Comment: The writer is being humorous and is using 'cod' old-fashioned English, as in "Here be dragons." (Unless it's a genuine mistake.)

Comment: @Mick Thank you for the comment. But as a non-native English speaker, I do not know that kind of 'cod' old-fashioned English and I do not understand how it can be used as a humorous gesture. May I ask you about this?

Comment: The term *cod* just means *fake*: not authentic. You often see "Here be dragons" (here are to be found dragons) on pirate maps in children's adventure books. Native English speakers are sometimes fond of using such idioms when posting on Internet forums. It is a whimsical form of humour. Perhaps the most famous 'cod' English accent is the exaggerated West Country / Bristol accent used by the actor Robert Newton in his portrayal of Long John Silver in the film [*Treasure Island*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yC_PR7YWQOc).

Comment: @Mick Thank you for the another answer. So helpful, you are a kind and smart man. If I may ask you more, can I ask you how "be" can mean "are to be"?

Comment: That is beyond my level of expertise. See: [What is the meaning of the phrase 'Here be dragons'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37086/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-here-be-dragons).